# How to remove black border effect around select element in IE 8 and less?

Tags: css, forms, internet-explorer, select, border

I have been searching for an hour on how to remove a black border/shadow around the top and left sides of a select element in IE 8 and less. Everything I have come across does not work.

I am using normalize.css and setting a 1 pixel solid red border around the error state of a select element.

Can someone tell me how to remove the black from the top and left sides? I have tried all sorts of things including the filter property, absolute positioning, and a few other things but nothing works.

Here's a zoomed in screenshot of what I'm referring to:

[image]

Comment: Please post the code you're using.

Comment: You get any solution? Josh's answer did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the following in your CSS:

```
select {
  outline: 0 !important;
}
```

However, styling the select element is a notoriously wonky endeavor.  Selects are much like file inputs in that browsers do not respect style rules applied to them.

If you'd like a more in-depth look at how these issues can be addressed, I highly recommend you check out this [previous post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)